# Laravel 8 - Call to a member function getRealPath() on null

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, attachment, sweetalert

**When I enter data, the attached data is not filled in**

I use Laravel for mail sending with attachment
it works, but after I add ajax sweet alert, it is not possible to attach a file from the input data, it simply ignores it and writes `Call to a member function getRealPath() on null`

It is sent controller

```
public function send(Request $request)
    {

        $data = [
            'name' => $request->name,
            'position' => $request->position,
            'phone' => $request->phone,
            'social' => $request->social,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'file' => $request->file('file')
        ];

        $to = 'nusamznaew@yandex.kz';

        Mail::to($to)->send(new SendMail($data));

        return redirect('/');
    }
```

This is the mailer function:

```
public function build()
    {

        $name = $this->data['name'];
        $position = $this->data['position'];
        $phone = $this->data['phone'];
        $social = $this->data['social'];
        $description = $this->data['description'];

        return $this->subject('Subject Email')
            ->view('mail.mail', compact('name', 'position', 'phone', 'social', 'description'))
            ->attach($this->data['file']->getRealPath(), [
                'as' => $this->data['file']->getClientOriginalName()
            ]);
    }
```

**It worked until I add ajax SweetAlert**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $(".ajax-form").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            /*Ajax Request Header setup*/
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });


            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '{{route("vacancy.send")}}',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (response) {
                    swal({
                        title: "Спасибо ваша заявка принята!",
                        icon: "success",
                        text: "Скоро наш менеджер с Вами свяжется",
                        showCancelButton: true,
                        confirmButtonColor: "#fff",
                    })
                }
            });

        });

    });
```

Comment: `it works, but after I add ajax sweet alert, it is not` any console errors? any PHP debugging info?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you sending data with ajax but in controller you retun redirect

if change to this

```
return redirect('/');
```

to this

```
return response()->json(["status" => "success"]);
```

and jquery do like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $(".ajax-form").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            /*Ajax Request Header setup*/
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '{{route("vacancy.send")}}',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                if(response.status === "success"){
                swal({
                    title: "Спасибо ваша заявка принята!",
                    icon: "success",
                    text: "Скоро наш менеджер с Вами свяжется",
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: "#fff",
                })
             }
            }
        });

    });

});
```

i hope it will work.